# use ArrayList Of Xobjects in class that work with ArrayList of YObjects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an adapter class with work with ArrayList KeyValue Object.

```
 class Adapter { 

      public Adapter(ArrayList<KeyValue> items){
       .....
      }

 }
```

and

```
class KeyValue {

     String name;
     int id;
     ...
}
```

but the problem is I have ArrayList of Fruits like this

```
class Fruits {

     String fruitName;
     int id;
     .....
}
```

is there any way to use ArrayList of Fruits without convert them to ArrayList of KeyValue "performance issue". and without using reflection"again performance issue"? maybe create a connector class?
of course, the main problem is there is a lot of different objects like Fruits.

Comment: if all your classes are key value pairs, its better to use Hashmaps to represent them

Comment: the problem is I don't create arrayLists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. You can, however declare a common base class though:

```
abstract class NamedObject {
    String name;
    int id;
};
```

but all your classes would have to inherit from it. If you can't change the definition of the classes, you use an additional object that can access the name and the id of the elements in the list:

```
interface Accessor<T> {
    String getName(T obj);
    int getId(T obj);
}
```

That would, of course affect performances.